# Powershell WPF Boolean resets its value after Function

Tags: .net, wpf, powershell

I started getting into some Powershell scripting to automate some processes in our company. I have been making steady progress the past few days but have ran into an issue which is making me think im insane. I have a boolean $canType defined in the global scope with a initial value of $true. I modify this boolean in a richTextBox eventhandler and set it to false. However after the function call the boolean is reset to its initial value and I have no idea why. Maybe someone can shed some light on the issue, i have some epxerience in programming and have never had such a problem, no other variables are reseting for no reason.

```
$global:canType = $true

$button3_Click = {
    $tempSettings = $settings | ConvertTo-Json
    $richTextBox1.AppendText($tempSettings)
}

$richTextBox1_KeyPress=[System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler]{
#Event Argument: $_ = [System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs]
    Write-Host 'Press: ' $canType
    if(!$canType) {
        $_.Handled = $true
    }
}

$richTextBox1_MouseUp = {
    Write-Host 'MouseUp Start : ' $canType
    $start = $richTextBox1.SelectionStart
    $end = $start + $richTextBox1.SelectionLength

    $startIndex = $richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex($start)
    $endIndex = $richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex($end)

    if($startIndex -ne $endIndex) {
        $canType = $false;
    }

    Write-Host 'MouseUp End : ' $canType
}
```

I have tried without $global: before, same result

Comment: To help you debug, you could think about adding a `Write-Host` line to this if condition `if($startIndex -ne $endIndex) {`.  This looks like the only place that would toggle the setting of the `$canType` variable, and if that condition isn't ever true, then the code isn't actually going to change the value of that variable.

Comment: @FoxDeploy I had a Write-Host there, the assignment works like a charm, $canType is correctly $false at the function end after selecting across lines. However the moment the function concludes the variable is reset. I have no logic implemeted to set it back to $true and it is definetly getting set to $false during the function call

Comment: You need to use `$global:canType` inside both the `KeyPress` and `MouseUp` scriptblocks you define, because without that inside the scriptblocks `$canType` is just a new undefined (and local to the scriptblock) variable. P.S. Probably using scope `$script:canType` would be sufficient, but since we cannot see the rest of your code I can't vouch for that..

Comment: @Theo is on the right path, see the answer I wrote which hopefully explains it further.

Comment: @Theo This is the correct answer! Thank you very much, such a weird behaviour, why does this not happen with objects or any other variable ? I have multiple vars without $global that dont reset at all, just this boolean

Comment: It's all due to PowerShell's pretty interesting variable inheritance / parent:child scope relationships.  This bites everyone in the bum at some point. Congrats, you've survived your first bum biter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking over the code more thoroughly, the issue is with variable inheritance.

It works pretty interestingly in PowerShell too.

You have a global variable at the top of your code which sets a `$global:` variable value.  Then you have some event handlers which trigger, these can be thought of as a function or scriptblock.

So simplifying your code a lot we have this:

```
function setCanType(){
    $canType = $false
    "local  canType value = $canType"
    "global canType value = $global:canType"
}

$global:canType = $true
"global cantype = $global:canType"
setCanType
"global cantype = $global:canType"
```

The output is this:

```
global cantype = True
local  canType value = False
global canType value = True
global cantype = True
```

See how the `$global:canType` stays True the whole time?  **This is the root of the issue**.  Now here's why in some more detail...

When your event handler fires, we get a new variable scope.  This child scope can see all of the parent values, so it effectively inherits the variables.

However, these are all new locally scoped variables.

[From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.1#parent-and-child-scopes):

> Unless you explicitly make the items private, the items in the parent scope are available to the child scope. However, items that you create and change in the child scope **do not affect the parent scope**, unless you explicitly specify the scope when you create the items.

As it's written, your code when the `If Condition` is true in the event handler will change the local variable value only.

That value is lost at the end of the event handler.

To fix it, use the `$global:` or `$script:` scope instead.